# Download persice i18n locale in Angularjs using Bower

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, bower

I'm using Wiredep tool with Gulp, to inject into my `index.html` on the run everything that I install using Bower. I don't want to download all the files [listed here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngLocale).
Is there a way to download only precise locale?
I've tried

```
bower install angular-i18n/angular-locale_uk-ua.js
```

And I got

```
fatal: remote error: 
  Repository not found.
```

Comment: No. You have to fork it if you don't want other files for some reason.

Comment: @estus Maybe provide this as an answer, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this [angular/bower-angular-i18n](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n) repo should be forked.

If the concern is to lower `bower_components` footprint on server side, [`postinstall` hook](http://bower.io/docs/config/#hooks) can be supplied in `.bowerrc` to delete extra files from the package after installation.